# Unsure if I am using the correct version of Java for Eclipse

Tags: java

I am having a bit of trouble determining if I am running the correct version of Eclipse and/or Java. I am attempting to make changes to a JAXB program for work. I can't run the program and an error is generated that states

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: RunISOPaymentFileSimulator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I know from doing my research using the search function this means that I need version J2SE 7.

After searching for my current version I find that I have Java 6 Standard Edition build 1.6.0.

My question is this: Is Java 6 the same thing as J2SE 6? Do I need to just update my Java version to 7 or do I need to also find the special J2SE 7?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error)

Comment: I'm curious you're working with JAXB, yet don't know the naming scheme for Java (not that it's *that* straightforward). But yes, you need to upgrade you version of Java to 7, i.e. `Java 1.7`, `Java SE 7` or just plain `Java 7`.

Comment: You can also add several JRE/JDK for your workspace or even run eclipse with parameter -vm "c:\...\java\bin" pointing to your desired java version. You can create a shortcut for that.

Comment: Haha that's a great question. The best way I can answer it as that sometimes we are thrust into opportunities we may not be ready for. We can either seize the opportunity and do the best we can or give up. If we do our best and ask for help and succeed, we may find it very worthwhile. 

That is to say I am given a task to do at my job and I saying "This is beyond my knowledge" isn't an option. I figure out how to do things one step at a time.. In this instance my first step is finding the right Java version. 

Thanks!

Comment: In fact, you should upgrade to Java 8. Java 7 is already EOL, and Java 9 is in alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Java not J2SE is specific enough.  What you need is the Java 7 JRE (Java Runtime Environment.)  You probably already have it but your JAVA_HOME is set to 6.  Changing your JAVA_HOME can cause issues for some applications that are written poorly so be prepared to have to switch it back.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

Comment: In my question I said "J2SE 7" not simply J2SE. My general question was "Is there any difference between Java 7 and J2SE 7. Please clarify this and I will make you as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Add any number you like to J2SE and Java and the answer stands.  J2SE stands for "Java 2 Standard Edition" if I recall correctly.  Java refers to any number of things including J2SE.  I guess technically you need the J2SE Runtime environment.  I've added the link for the Oracle version but you can also get other implementations.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response in marking this as an accepted answer.. Holidays and such :)